# What is the difference between the GNU Makefile variable assignments =, ?=, := and +=?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Can anybody give a clear explanation of how variable assignment really works in Makefiles.

What is the difference between :

```
 VARIABLE = value
 VARIABLE ?= value
 VARIABLE := value
 VARIABLE += value
```

I have read the [section](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading-Makefiles) in GNU Make's manual, but it still doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1245, accepted):

#### Lazy Set

```
VARIABLE = value
```

Normal setting of a variable, but any other variables mentioned with the `value` field are recursively expanded with their value at the point at which the variable is used, not the one it had when it was declared

#### Immediate Set

```
VARIABLE := value
```

Setting of a variable with simple expansion of the values inside - values within it are expanded at declaration time.

#### Lazy Set If Absent

```
VARIABLE ?= value
```

Setting of a variable only if it doesn't have a value. `value` is always evaluated when `VARIABLE` is accessed. It is equivalent to

```
ifeq ($(origin VARIABLE), undefined)
  VARIABLE = value
endif
```

See the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html#Flavors) for more details.

#### Append

```
VARIABLE += value
```

Appending the supplied value to the existing value (or setting to that value if the variable didn't exist)

Comment: Does A += B expand B? That is if if I do A += B, and then B += C, would A evaluate to concatenation of ${B} and ${C}?

Comment: As the linked section of the manual says. += operates according to whatever simple or recursive semantics the original assignment had. So yes, it will expand the RHS but whether it does that immediately or in a deferred manner depends on the type of the variable on the LHS.

Comment: What do you mean when you say variable value is expanded?

Comment: @СашкоЛихенко have a look here to get meaning of expansion 
http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors

Comment: is "set if absent" lazy or immediate? can i "lazy set if absent" and "immediate set if abset"?

Comment: So... In more simple terms `=` is referenced and `:=` is an actual copy by value?

Comment: using `=` will mutate the reference variable, if any mutation happen.
using `:=` will is clone the the reference, so if any mutation happen, it wont affect the reference variable

https://riptutorial.com/makefile/example/21468/recursively-expanded-variables

Comment: The `Lazy set` title is misleading, and `when the variable is used, not when it's declared` is unclear on one important matter: `=`-style variable is expanded EACH time it's evaluated. For example, `AAA=$(shell date)` can have different values in the same run.
In make manual, is not called "lazy", it's called "recursively expanded".

Comment: @VictorSergienko I do refer to "recursively expanded" in the explanation, and "lazy evaluation" is a well known term.

Comment: Right, and "Lazy evaluation" is NOT what `make` does here. Lazy evaluation works once, when a value is first accessed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation. `make` re-evaluates a recursively expanded variable each time.

Comment: This reads way better than the GNU manual equivalent.

Comment: Is it worth mentioning the override directive here?  If a the user set VARIABLE with a command-line argument (or a previous override) then none of these assignments should change VARIABLE unless preceded with the override directive.  Example:
override VARIABLE += value

Comment: @Etan Reisner: What if there is no original assignment (LHS) for an append (+=)? The first append creates the value, right? Will it be simple or recursive? I'm guessing recursive.

Comment: I think the "Lazy Set" in this answer should be re-labeled as "Dynamic value" because it causes maximum possible re-computations for the value but allows it to dynamically change as a result of other things changing. It's closer to setting a reference to a closure that re-computes value on the fly every time.

Answer (score 338):

Using **`=`** causes the variable to be assigned a value.  If the variable already had a value, it is replaced.  This value will be expanded when it is used.  For example:

```
HELLO = world
HELLO_WORLD = $(HELLO) world!

# This echoes "world world!"
echo $(HELLO_WORLD)

HELLO = hello

# This echoes "hello world!"
echo $(HELLO_WORLD)
```

Using **`:=`** is similar to using `=`.  However, instead of the value being expanded when it is used, it is expanded during the assignment.  For example:

```
HELLO = world
HELLO_WORLD := $(HELLO) world!

# This echoes "world world!"
echo $(HELLO_WORLD)

HELLO = hello

# Still echoes "world world!"
echo $(HELLO_WORLD)

HELLO_WORLD := $(HELLO) world!

# This echoes "hello world!"
echo $(HELLO_WORLD)
```

Using **`?=`** assigns the variable a value *iff* the variable was not previously assigned.  If the variable was previously assigned a blank value (`VAR=`), it is still considered set *I think*.  Otherwise, functions exactly like `=`.

Using **`+=`** is like using `=`, but instead of replacing the value, the value is appended to the current one, with a space in between.  If the variable was previously set with `:=`, it is expanded *I think*.  The resulting value is expanded when it is used *I think*.  For example:

```
HELLO_WORLD = hello
HELLO_WORLD += world!

# This echoes "hello world!"
echo $(HELLO_WORLD)
```

If something like `HELLO_WORLD = $(HELLO_WORLD) world!` were used, recursion would result, which would most likely end the execution of your Makefile.  If `A := $(A) $(B)` were used, the result would not be the exact same as using `+=` because `B` is expanded with `:=` whereas `+=` would not cause `B` to be expanded.

Comment: a consequence of that is therefore
`VARIABLE = literal` and `VARIABLE := literal` are always equivalent. Did I get that right?

Comment: @aiao, yes as literals are invariant to their uses

Comment: A subtle difference is:- ?: can improve performance in recursive called makefiles. For e.g if $? = $(shell some_command_that_runs_long_time). In recursive calls this will be evaluated only once. causing gains in build performance. := will be slower since the command is needlessly running multiple times

Answer (score 79):

I suggest you do some experiments using "make". Here is a simple demo, showing the difference between `=` and `:=`.

```
/* Filename: Makefile*/
x := foo
y := $(x) bar
x := later

a = foo
b = $(a) bar
a = later

test:
    @echo x - $(x)
    @echo y - $(y)
    @echo a - $(a)
    @echo b - $(b)
```

`make test` prints:

```
x - later
y - foo bar
a - later
b - later bar
```

[Check more elaborate explanation here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151113045702/http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/make-3.79/html_chapter/make_6.html)

Comment: It would be better to use a `@` in front each recipe to avoid this confusing repetition of results.

Comment: Make does not support `/* ... */` block comment

Answer (score 39):

When you use `VARIABLE = value`, if `value` is actually a reference to another variable, then the value is only determined when `VARIABLE` is used. This is best illustrated with an example:

```
VAL = foo
VARIABLE = $(VAL)
VAL = bar

# VARIABLE and VAL will both evaluate to "bar"
```

When you use `VARIABLE := value`, you get the value of `value` *as it is now*. For example:

```
VAL = foo
VARIABLE := $(VAL)
VAL = bar

# VAL will evaluate to "bar", but VARIABLE will evaluate to "foo"
```

Using `VARIABLE ?= val` means that you only set the value of `VARIABLE` *if* `VARIABLE` is not set already. If it's not set already, the setting of the value is deferred until `VARIABLE` is used (as in example 1).

`VARIABLE += value` just appends `value` to `VARIABLE`. The actual value of `value` is determined as it was when it was initially set, using either `=` or `:=`.

Comment: Actually, in your first example, VARIABLE is $(VAL) and VAL is bar.  VARIABLE expanded when it is used.

Comment: Yes, the comments are explaining what would happen when they are used.

Comment: Ah; I guess you corrected it, or I misread "evaluate" as "be."

Answer (score 10):

In the above answers, **it is important to understand** what is meant by "values are expanded at declaration/use time". Giving a value like `*.c` does not entail any expansion. It is only when this string is used by a command that it will maybe trigger some globbing. Similarly, a value like `$(wildcard *.c)` or `$(shell ls *.c)` does not entail any expansion and is completely evaluated at definition time even if we used `:=` in the variable definition.

Try the following Makefile in directory where you have some C files:

```
VAR1 = *.c
VAR2 := *.c
VAR3 = $(wildcard *.c)
VAR4 := $(wildcard *.c)
VAR5 = $(shell ls *.c)
VAR6 := $(shell ls *.c)

all :
    touch foo.c
    @echo "now VAR1 = \"$(VAR1)\"" ; ls $(VAR1)
    @echo "now VAR2 = \"$(VAR2)\"" ; ls $(VAR2)
    @echo "now VAR3 = \"$(VAR3)\"" ; ls $(VAR3)
    @echo "now VAR4 = \"$(VAR4)\"" ; ls $(VAR4)
    @echo "now VAR5 = \"$(VAR5)\"" ; ls $(VAR5)
    @echo "now VAR6 = \"$(VAR6)\"" ; ls $(VAR6)
    rm -v foo.c
```

Running `make` will trigger a rule that creates an extra (empty) C file, called `foo.c` but none of the 6 variables has `foo.c` in its value.

Comment: This is a great call and has plenty of examples for expansion at declaration time, it'd be useful to extend the answer with an example and some words for expansion at use time

Answer (score 9):

The most upvoted answer can be improved.

Let me refer to GNU Make manual ["Setting variables"](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Setting.html#Setting) and ["Flavors"](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html#Flavors), and add some comments.

#### Recursively expanded variables

> The value you specify is installed verbatim; if it contains references to other variables, these references are expanded whenever this variable is substituted (in the course of expanding some other string). When this happens, it is called *recursive expansion*.

```
foo = $(bar)
```

**The catch**: `foo` will be expanded to the value of `$(bar)` **each time** `foo` is evaluated, possibly resulting in different values. Surely you cannot call it "lazy"! This can surprise you if executed on midnight:

```
# This variable is haunted!
WHEN = $(shell date -I)

something:
    touch $(WHEN).flag

# If this is executed on 00:00:00:000, $(WHEN) will have a different value!
something-else-later: something
    test -f $(WHEN).flag || echo "Boo!"
```

#### Simply expanded variable

```
VARIABLE := value
VARIABLE ::= value
```

> Variables defined with ‘:=’ or ‘::=’ are simply expanded variables.

> Simply expanded variables are defined by lines using ‘:=’ or ‘::=’ [...]. Both forms are equivalent in GNU make; however only the ‘::=’ form is described by the POSIX standard [...] 2012.

> The value of a simply expanded variable is scanned once and for all, expanding any references to other variables and functions, when the variable is defined.

Not much to add. It's evaluated immediately, including recursive expansion of, well, recursively expanded variables.

**The catch**: If `VARIABLE` refers to `ANOTHER_VARIABLE`:

```
VARIABLE := $(ANOTHER_VARIABLE)-yohoho
```

and `ANOTHER_VARIABLE` is not defined before this assignment, `ANOTHER_VARIABLE` will expand to an empty value.

#### Assign if not set

```
FOO ?= bar
```

is equivalent to

```
ifeq ($(origin FOO), undefined)
FOO = bar
endif
```

where `$(origin FOO)` equals to `undefined` only if the variable was not set at all.

**The catch**: if `FOO` was set to an empty string, either in makefiles, shell environment, or command line overrides, it will **not** be assigned `bar`.

#### Appending

```
VAR += bar
```

[Appending](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Appending.html):

> When the variable in question has not been defined before, ‘+=’ acts just like normal ‘=’: it defines a recursively-expanded variable. However, when there is a previous definition, exactly what ‘+=’ does depends on what flavor of variable you defined originally.

So, this will print `foo bar`:

```
VAR = foo
# ... a mile of code
VAR += $(BAR)
BAR = bar
$(info $(VAR))
```

but this will print `foo`:

```
VAR := foo
# ... a mile of code
VAR += $(BAR)
BAR = bar
$(info $(VAR))
```

**The catch** is that `+=` behaves differently depending on what type of variable `VAR` was assigned before.

#### Multiline values

The [syntax to assign multiline value to a variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multi_002dLine.html) is:

```
define VAR_NAME :=
line
line
endef
```

or

```
define VAR_NAME =
line
line
endef
```

Assignment operator can be omitted, then it creates a recursively-expanded variable.

```
define VAR_NAME
line
line
endef
```

The last newline before `endef` is removed.

#### Bonus: the shell assignment operator ‘!=’

```
 HASH != printf '\043'
```

is the same as

```
HASH := $(shell printf '\043')
```

Don't use it. `$(shell)` call is more readable, and the usage of both in a makefiles is highly discouraged. At least, `$(shell)` follows Joel's advice and [makes wrong code look obviously wrong](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/).

Comment: Are `?=` and `=` equivalent when defining macros that are intended to be overridden by environment variables, like `CFLAGS`/`CPPFLAGS`/`LDFLAGS`?

Comment: @shadowtalker, no. Make variables default to environment variables, but `=` overrides any existing value.
Also note that command-line *override* variables (that go *after* `make` on command line) override every single assignment in `Makefile`, except for [overrides](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Override-Directive.html).

Comment: Does this sound correct? `=` and `:=` override environment variables, environment variables override `=?`, command-line "override variables" override both, and the `override` directive overrides all of the above. This interaction with environment variables and command-line override might be a very helpful clarification in your already-very-thorough answer.

Comment: This is accurate. Thank you. I thought that this is a bit outside of the scope of the question. On the other hand, there is no question "How do Makefile variables get their values?". Maybe it's worth asking the question.

Comment: I took your suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68825174/2954547