# Difference between assignment operators in automake

Tags: automake, assignment-operator

There are 2 variants of assignments in automake.
= and :=
Is there a difference between them?

Answer (score 3):

There's more than those two and they're from makefiles, not automake specifically.

See [Makefile variable assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448910/makefile-variable-assignment)

Comment: Note that if you use a `:=` assignment with `-Wall` passed to `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE`, you get the following error: `Makefile.am:12: \`:='-style assignments are not portable`