# What's the difference between := and = in Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, colon-equals

For variable assignment in Make, I see := and = operator. What's the difference between them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Makefile variable assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448910/makefile-variable-assignment)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between the GNU Makefile variable assignments =, ?=, := and +=?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448910/what-is-the-difference-between-the-gnu-makefile-variable-assignments-a)

Answer (score 124, accepted):

This is described in the GNU Make documentation, in the section titled [6.2 The Two Flavors of Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html#Flavors)
.

In short, variables defined with `:=` are expanded once, but variables defined with `=` are expanded whenever they are used.

Comment: So would it be correct to say that := is more efficient? Or is efficiency not really a factor with Makefiles?

Comment: @Ungeheuer That's not an issue because process calling (the `make`'s main job) has much larger overhead than such internal variable resolving.

Answer (score 193):

#### Simple assignment `:=`

A simple assignment expression is evaluated only once, at the very first occurrence. 
For example, if `CC :=${GCC} ${FLAGS}` during the first encounter is evaluated to `gcc -W` then 
each time `${CC}` occurs it will be replaced with `gcc -W`.

#### Recursive assignment `=`

A Recursive assignment expression is evaluated everytime the variable is encountered 
in the code. For example, a statement like `CC = ${GCC} {FLAGS}` will be evaluated only when
 an action like `${CC} file.c` is executed. However, if the variable `GCC` is reassigned i.e
`GCC=c++` then the `${CC}` will be converted to `c++ -W` after the reassignment.

#### Conditional assignment `?=`

Conditional assignment assigns a value to a variable only if it does not have a value

#### Appending `+=`

Assume that `CC = gcc` then the appending operator is used like `CC += -w`
then `CC` now has the value `gcc -W`

For more check out these [tutorials](https://github.com/amjadmajid/Makefile)

Comment: "A simple assignment expression is evaluated only once, at the very first occurrence": to be clear, the expansion/evaluation is done when the variable is defined, not the first time it is used.

Answer (score 65):

For me, the best way to see it in practice is during this Makefile snippet:

#### Simple assignment

```
XX := $(shell date) # date will be executed once
tt:
    @echo $(XX)
    sleep 2
    @echo $(XX)
```

Running

```
make tt
```

Will produce:

```
sex 22 jan 2021 14:56:08 -03
sex 22 jan 2021 14:56:08 -03
```

( **Same** value )

#### Expanded assignment

```
XX = $(shell date) # date will be executed every time you use XX
tt:
    @echo $(XX)
    sleep 2
    @echo $(XX)
```

Running

```
make tt
```

Will produce:

```
sex 22 jan 2021 14:56:08 -03
sex 22 jan 2021 14:56:10 -03
```

**Different** values

Comment: `//` isn't a valid comment in Makefiles

Comment: interesting choice of `$(shell sleep 2)` instead of just calling `sleep 2`. The result is really different between the two. Why did you chose `%(shell ...)`?

Comment: @Eric, I fixed the usage of the comment. Thanks for the suggestion. About the use of `shell sleep 2`, I think it works well with just `sleep 2`. When I created this answer, I copied this code from a `Makefile` that used the result to assign it to a variable. This is the reason to use `$(shell ...)`, which was something like: `result:=$(find . -type f -name '*js'`.

Comment: This answer, I like better.

Answer (score 12):

From http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors:

`=` defines a recursively-expanded variable.  `:=` defines a simply-expanded variable.

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question but this example helps me understand the difference whenever I forget.

Running `make` with the following Makefile will instantly exit:

```
a = $(shell sleep 3)
```

Running `make` with the following Makefile will sleep for 3 seconds, and then exit:

```
a := $(shell sleep 3)
```

In the former Makefile, `a` is not evaluated until it's used elsewhere in the Makefile, while in the latter `a` is evaluated immediately even though it's not used.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive assignment `=` is evaluated everytime it is used, but not in the order of when it is encountered among the recipe commands, but rather **before** running any recipe command.

Based on the following example:

```
default: target1 target2

target1 target2:
    @echo "Running at:           `gdate +%s.%N`"
    @echo "Simple assignment:    $(SIMPLE_ASSIGNMENT)"
    @echo "Recursive assignment: $(RECURSIVE_ASSIGNMENT)"
    sleep 1
    @echo "Running at:           `gdate +%s.%N`"
    @echo "Simple assignment:    $(SIMPLE_ASSIGNMENT)"
    @echo "Recursive assignment: $(RECURSIVE_ASSIGNMENT)"
    @echo


SIMPLE_ASSIGNMENT := $(shell gdate +%s.%N)
RECURSIVE_ASSIGNMENT = $(shell gdate +%s.%N)
```

Outputs:

```
❯ make
Running at:           1645056840.980488000
Simple assignment:    1645056840.949181000
Recursive assignment: 1645056840.958590000
sleep 1
Running at:           1645056842.008998000
Simple assignment:    1645056840.949181000
Recursive assignment: 1645056840.969616000

Running at:           1645056842.047367000
Simple assignment:    1645056840.949181000
Recursive assignment: 1645056842.027600000
sleep 1
Running at:           1645056843.076696000
Simple assignment:    1645056840.949181000
Recursive assignment: 1645056842.035901000
```

Answer (score 1):

`=`  called  recursive expanded variable or lazy expanded variable. in below example, when make read this line

```
VAR1 = $(VAR1) + 100
```

make just stored value from righthand side VAR1 into lefthand side VAR1 without expanding. When make tried to read $(VAR1) which is defined on left hand side. this is keep repeating and result into infinite loop

```
VAR1 = 10
VAR2 = 20
VAR3 = 30

# Lazy initialization
VAR1 = $(VAR1) + 100

default:
    echo $(VAR1)
```

**Output:**

```
% make
Makefile:6: *** Recursive variable `VAR1' references itself (eventually).  Stop.
```

`:=` called expanded variable or instant

when make read this line, variable on righthand side are expnaded and saved resulting value into left hand side. please see below program output

```
VAR1 = 10
VAR2 = 20
VAR3 = 30

# instant initialization
VAR1 := $(VAR1) + 100

default:
    echo $(VAR1)

% make
echo 10 + 100
10 + 100
```

**Output:**

```
% make
echo 10 + 100
10 + 100
```

EDIT:
There are already good answer. I came across about this concept on  Udemy training course of make with good example.