# What does :=$= means in Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

On this Makefile: https://github.com/GrapheneOS/platform_frameworks_base/blob/11/Android.mk I found

```
SDK_METADATA_DIR :=$= $(call intermediates-dir-for,PACKAGING,framework-doc-stubs-metadata,,COMMON)
```

What does `:=$=` means?

I found nothing here: [What's the difference between := and = in Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879592/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-makefile) neither on the links provided

Comment: The `:=` part should be an immediate assignment.  The `$=` should be a single-character macro — it is less clear what that means.  It was not a part of the original versions of `make` AFAIK/AFAICR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the book [thegnumakebook](http://www.rgonzo.us/shiny/books/thegnumakebook.pdf), page 126, The Twilight Zone:

> It’s possible to take definitions like $( ) and $(\n) and go much
> further, defining variables with names like =, # or :

I think, `=` is just some other variable. Here, `$=` implies, expanding the variable `=`.

And `:=` is used for simple assignment (Evaluated only once).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like "$=" is a place holder, so space behind "$=" can be kepted.

```
DEPMOD_STAGING_SUBDIR :=$= lib/modules/0.0
DEPMOD_STAGING_SUBDIR1 := lib/modules/0.0

target:
        echo "|"${DEPMOD_STAGING_SUBDIR}"|"
        echo "|"${DEPMOD_STAGING_SUBDIR1}"|"
        echo "|"$="|"
```

output is:

```
echo "|" lib/modules/0.0"|"
| lib/modules/0.0|
echo "|"lib/modules/0.0"|"
|lib/modules/0.0|
echo "|""|"
||
```