# Why can make work here?

Tags: linux, makefile

Makefile:

```
KERNEL_DIR := /usr/src/linux-2.6.32.9

obj-m := try.o

driver:     try.c
    make -C $(KERNEL_DIR) SUBDIRS=`pwd` modules
clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.ko *.mod.c
```

When I type `make`,`make -C $(KERNEL_DIR) SUBDIRS=`pwd`modules` is run,as if `make driver` is run ,why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`make` runs the first possible thing from a makefile if called without an argument. `obj-m` and `KERNEL_DIR` are not rules, they are variables. `driver` is the first rule to follow.

Comment: But in `driver` there's no `try.o`,how?

Comment: `obj-m` (and `KERNEL_DIR`) are not targets, but variables. `driver` is the first target and hence executed by make, if no concrete target is given on invocation

Comment: What's the `try.c` behind target `driver` for?

Comment: @assem: It's a dependency. It means that `driver` uses `try.c`, and if `try.c` has been modified from the last time you called `make`, `driver` will be rebuilt.

Comment: Isn't dependency specified by `:=`,not `:` ?

Comment: @assem: They are both dependency declarations with a bit different meanings. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448910/makefile-variable-assignment

Comment: There's a bit of confusion going on here. @jho: No, `:=` and `:` are not both dependency declarations; only the last one is. The first one is a variable assignment, similar to `=`; to read about the difference see the [GNU make manual (paragraph 6.2)](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors). @assem: A single colon (`:`) separates a target and its dependencies.

Comment: @eriktous, what about `make -C $(KERNEL_DIR) SUBDIRS=`pwd` modules`,why it doesn't take any parameters?

Comment: @assem: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "it doesn't take any parameters"? This is just a command that runs make in the directory `$(KERNEL_DIR)`, with the variable `SUBDIRS` set to the current directory, and instructs make to build the target `modules`. There should be a Makefile in the directory `$(KERNEL_DIR)` which contains a rule that describes how to update `modules`.

Answer (score 1):

If make is invoked without specifying a goal, make chooses the first target in the makefile as a goal. In this cases, it is `driver`. `obj-m` and `KERNEL_DIR` are only variable assignments, not targets.

Comment: Can you talk about what exactly happened for `make driver` ?