# What does this make command do?

Tags: linux, makefile

```
make -C $(KERNEL_DIR) SUBDIRS=pwd` modules
```

Can someone elaborate this?

Comment: Are you sure about that backtick (`)?

Comment: I am pretty sure he means \`pwd\`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can make work here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388224/why-can-make-work-here)

Comment: Never type, always copy-paste commands or error messages, especially when you don't understand them.

Answer (score 2):

The `-C` means "change to this directory before starting make." The SUBDIRS is a variable used by the Linux kernel make system. SUBDIRS=`pwd` means that the kernel makefiles should look in the current directory, because `pwd` means "print working directory." And `modules` means to make modules.

It probably uses the kernel make system to build an out-of-tree module. Out-of-tree means a kernel module that is not shipped with the kernel.

In fact, I seem to recall seeing this command used as part of the Nvidia binary module installer.

Comment: So to build a kernel module,only `SUBDIRS` is required,not specific files?How does it know which modules to compile?

Comment: because this line is part of a Makefile, and the target are in the Makefile