# := vs = in make macros

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, colon-equals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between the GNU Makefile variable assignments =, ?=, := and +=?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448910/makefile-variable-assignment)

I only know very basic `makefile` syntax, and was reading through another project's `makefile` and came across `:=` for macro declaration. Why would they use that?

In other words, is there any difference between

```
MYMACRO = hi i'm a macro
```

and

```
MYMACRO := hi i'm a macro
```

?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448910/makefile-variable-assignment

Comment: see in particular http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors

Comment: So there is no difference in the examples of the question, but there would be if MYMACRO used another macro and the value of the other macro could change while the makefile is being processed.

Comment: @cnicutar `'info' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` 

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Variables defined with `:=` in [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors) are expanded when they are defined rather than when they are used.

Comment: Could you explain some more, what "expand" invokes?

Comment: @rubo77 *Expand* mean replacing `$variable` by its `value`. See here for more details http://stackoverflow.com/a/30215530/5016540

Comment: An example would be beneficial.  I found the linked answer in the "duplicate" was a bit more explanatory.

Comment: some example would help here

Comment: Example

**=** is used for _recursive expansions_.
Meaning that the value on the right-hand side is not immediately evaluated. This makes things like this possible:

```
A = $(B) world
B = hello
all:
    @echo $(A)
```

Output: `hello world`

The **:=** instead is used for immediate evaluation. Running the above Makefile with this symbol would only result in "world" being displayed.