# := versus = error: undefined reference to qMain(int, char**)

Tags: c++, windows, qt, makefile

**Qt 4.6.1**

In the following .pro file, when I use the statement

```
sources = ef.cpp
```

I get following errors:

```
RInside.h: No such file or directory
```

[image]

Then when I replace = with := like:

```
sources := ef.cpp
```

the above error vanishes, and I get a new error:

```
error: undefined reference to qMain(int, char**)
```

[image]

From here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/448939/462608

> VARIABLE = value Normal setting of a variable - values within it are
>   recursively expanded when the variable is used, not when it's declared
>
> VARIABLE := value Setting of a variable with simple expansion of the
>   values inside - values within it are expanded at declaration time.

**I wish to understand what's happening here, and what's the solution.**

**.cpp**

```
#include <RInside.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    RInside R(argc, argv);

    R["txt"] = "Hello, world!\n";

    R.parseEvalQ ("cat(txt)");

    exit(0);
}
```

**.pro**

```
TEMPLATE    = app
TARGET      = 
DEPENDPATH  += .
INCLUDEPATH += .

R_HOME  := 'c:/R-2.15.1'

# Input
sources  = ef.cpp
programs := $(sources:.cpp=)

## include headers and libraries for R
RCPPFLAGS :=        $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R $(R_ARCH) CMD config --cppflags)
RLDFLAGS  :=        $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R $(R_ARCH) CMD config --ldflags)
RBLAS     :=        $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R $(R_ARCH) CMD config BLAS_LIBS)
RLAPACK   :=        $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R $(R_ARCH) CMD config LAPACK_LIBS)

## include headers and libraries for Rcpp interface classes
RCPPINCL  :=        $(shell echo 'Rcpp:::CxxFlags()' | $(R_HOME)/bin/R $(R_ARCH) --vanilla 

--slave)
RCPPLIBS  :=        $(shell echo 'Rcpp:::LdFlags()'  | $(R_HOME)/bin/R $(R_ARCH) --vanilla --slave)


## include headers and libraries for RInside embedding classes
RINSIDEINCL :=      $(shell echo 'RInside:::CxxFlags()' | $(R_HOME)/bin/R $(R_ARCH) --vanilla --slave)
RINSIDELIBS :=      $(shell echo 'RInside:::LdFlags()'  | $(R_HOME)/bin/R $(R_ARCH) --vanilla --slave)


## compiler etc settings used in default make rules
CXX        := $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R $(R_ARCH) CMD config CXX)
CPPFLAGS   := -Wall $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R $(R_ARCH) CMD config CPPFLAGS)
#CXXFLAGS  := $(RCPPFLAGS) $(RCPPINCL) $(RINSIDEINCL) $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R $(R_ARCH) 

CMD config CXXFLAGS)
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS := $(RCPPFLAGS) $(RCPPINCL) $(RINSIDEINCL) $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R $(R_ARCH) CMD config CXXFLAGS)
LDFLAGS    = -s
QMAKE_LIBS := $(RLDFLAGS) $(RBLAS) $(RLAPACK) $(RINSIDELIBS) $(RCPPLIBS)
CC         := $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R $(R_ARCH) CMD config CXX)
```

Comment: Looks like the change you've already made gets you to the link stage.  Do you have a `qMain(int, char**)`?  And is it actually being compiled?

Comment: @cHao I have already posted the only source code that I have. I have not specially written qMain anywhere. If you meant something else, please clarify.

Comment: What i'm seeing hints to me that the linker can't find the main function.  Meaning it either doesn't exist at all, has the wrong name, or is not in any of the files being compiled.  Where and how is your main function defined? n If you don't have one, how is this stuff supposed to work?

Comment: @cHao `If you don't have one, how is this stuff supposed to work? ` You are perhaps getting me wrong. I have the `main` function but I don't have the `qMain` function. The error is different when I replace `:=` with `=`. See OP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't look like a Qt project, so you should probably disable linking against Qt libs.  Set `QT` and `CONFIG` to be empty:

```
QT =
CONFIG =
```

If on other hand this *is* a Qt project that should link against Qt libraries, then the problem is that you're overwriting vital variables, like `QMAKE_LIBS` and `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS`. Use `+=`, not `:=`. Also, use `LIBS`, not `QMAKE_LIBS`.