# := and ?= in Makefile

Tags: makefile

[image]
As shown in the figure, what the difference between :=, ?= and =
I did a quick search without find out a good answer. Appreciate it.

Comment: Check out the [GNU Make Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html). Sections 3.7, 6.2 and 6.3 for starters.

Comment: Please find a good answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448910/makefile-variable-assignment