# What does this do in makefiles?

Tags: makefile

Here is the line that bothers me:

```
CFLAGS+=-DCONTIKI_VERSION_THINKSQUARE=1
```

There are so many signs one after another (+=-) that totally confuses me :)
I know that += is append operator, but the right side is unknown for me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/q/448910/2968959

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole right side of `+=` is interpreted as a string that is appended to the makefile variable `CFLAGS`. Say, your makefile is:

```
CFLAGS:=VAL1
CFLAGS+=-DCONTIKI_VERSION_THINKSQUARE=1

all:
    @echo $(CFLAGS)
```

`make all` will output:

```
VAL1 -DCONTIKI_VERSION_THINKSQUARE=1
```

Comment: But isn't -D some kind of directive like

    #define CONTIKI_VERSION_THINKSQUARE   1

Comment: @Radoslaw Krasimirow: Make doesn't care what is `-D`. You asked what happens in makefile language. What happens if you pass the `CFLAGS` to `gcc` is a different issue altogether!