# configuration file for virtual machine

Tags: linux, shell

Actually i have to modify one configuration file for mine virtual machine. I got on file named "`local.conf`".

In this file there is line on which following is written :

```
DL_DIR ?= ${topdir}/downloads
```

What is the meaning of this and also *what is significance of dollar* command in linux shell.

In fact there are several commands in this file which starts with dollar command.

Comment: What kind of virtualisation software do you use? What exactly do you need to change in the file and why?

Comment: Thanks for reply.Actually i am using Oracle VM virtual box. In this virtual machine i am trying to build an boot image for embedded linux called the"Yocto Linux".So to build this i got an pre wriiten script file named "local.conf" and this need to customised as per mine requirement. But as i mentioned there are many commands in this file which are dolar sign either at the end or start and unable to understand the function of these  lines. Unless i will understand this i can not customise this fully.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448910/makefile-variable-assignment

Comment: In mine config file there is one more line on which following is written.            Machine ??= "zedboard". I went through the links that you have posted and i understood the things. But what is meaning of double question mark(??) in the assignment.