# variable assignment of Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I saw the question:

[makefile-variable-assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448910/makefile-variable-assignment)

then I did as below:

```
HELLO='hello 1st'
HELLO_WORLD='$(HELLO) world!'
HELLO='hello 2nd'

all :
    echo $(HELLO_WORLD)
    HELLO='hello 3rd'
    echo $(HELLO_WORLD)
    HELLO='hello 4th'
    echo $(HELLO_WORLD)
```

the result is that:

```
root@ubuntu:~# make all -s
hello 2nd world!
hello 2nd world!
hello 2nd world!
```

I confused, why the value of 'HELLO' was not set to `hello 4th` but `hello 2nd`

update：

I update my code ：

```
HELLO='hello 1st'
HELLO_WORLD='$(HELLO) world!'
HELLO='hello 2nd'

all :
    HELLO='hello 3rd' &&  echo $(HELLO_WORLD)
    HELLO='hello 4th' &&  echo $(HELLO_WORLD)
```

And the result:

```
root@ubuntu:~# make all -s 
hello 2nd world!
hello 2nd world!
```

I have realized the sentences like `HELLO='hello 3rd'` is not variable assignments finally.
You two help me a lot. Thanks the answers!

Comment: Exercise: And can you see why `HELLO='hello 3rd'; echo $(HELLO); echo $$HELLO` outputs what it does?

Comment: the output is `hello 3rd` and a blank line

Comment: `echo $$HELLO` is equal to `echo $('hello 3rd')`

Comment: I meant with your definitions of `HELLO` first.  The first `$(HELLO)` is a makefile variable, and _make_ expands it to `hello 2nd` – but the `$$HELLO` includes the make variable `$$`, which expands to `$`, so that make expands this line to `HELLO='hello 3rd'; echo hello 2nd; echo $HELLO` and _that_ sequence of three commands is what it executes in the shell. At that point, the _shell_ (1) defines the variable `HELLO`, then (2) echoes the two literal arguments `hello` and `2nd`, then (3) expands the _shell_ variable `$HELLO` to `hello 3rd` and prints that. Hence `hello 2nd` then `hello 3rd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines like

```
HELLO='hello 3rd'
```

are not (make) variable assignments, but lines in the rule action.

The [relevant section of the make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Setting.html) says that the variable has to be at the start of the line.

As you've written it, the `HELLO=...` lines are simply action lines.  In these cases, the command `HELLO='hello 3rd'` sets the *shell* variable `HELLO` in a new shell, which then immediately exits (as the answer form @sergei-kurenkov mentions, each line is executed in a different shell).

Answer (score 0):

> why the terminal print not `hello 4th world` but `hello 2nd world`

Each line in recipes is executed in its own shell. So after you have uncommented 4 lines the for the target 'all' you run shell 5 times and enviroment variables in set in first run will not be seen in the second run and so forth.

Source: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Execution.html#Execution