# makefile: Is it possible to let rule call rule process inherit variable values?

Tags: makefile

I want to call rule inside another rule. So I tried to write the following test makefile

```
var = 11

a:
    echo $(var)
    $(eval var=22)
    echo $(var)
    $(MAKE) b

b:
    echo $(var)
```

The problem is that when I run `make a`, the `$(MAKE) b` will still output `11`, but I wish it should be `22`. So my problem is : Is there a way to inherit variable values across different rules?

Answer (score 2):

If you're in the same file, you should avoid this altogether -- stop thinking of `make` as some "advanced scripting tool". It is not. It's a tool for building files doing the minimum necessary work while respecting all dependencies and therefore, your job is to exactly state these dependencies using *prerequisites*.

Look at this example and what it does:

```
var = 11

printvar:
    echo $(var)

setvar:
    $(eval var=22)

a:  printvar setvar b

b:  
    echo $(var)

.PHONY: a b printvar setvar
```

Note that **none** of these rules create an actual file. Normally, a rule should create its target, if it isn't, it must be listed as a prerequisite of the special target `.PHONY` to let make know this. This should be an exception -- the primary use of `make` is that it can decide whether it has to apply a rule by comparing the timestamps of the prerequisites with that of the target. A rule's recipe is only executed if there's a prerequisite that is newer than the target. With a `.PHONY` rule, the recipe has to be executed each and every time.

---

When talking about recursive `make`, the question would make some more sense. One easy way to pass a variable from a parent `make` process to a child is to *export* it to the environment. In your example, the following would do:

```
var ?= 11      # only set var if it doesn't have a value yet
export var     # export var to the environment, so it's available to child make

a:
    echo $(var)
    $(eval var=22)
    echo $(var)
    $(MAKE) b

b:
    echo $(var)

.PHONY: a b
```

Of course, this only makes sense in practice when you have **different** Makefiles, so not just call `$(MAKE) b`, but e.g. `$(MAKE) -C [some subdir] b`. IMHO, *recursive make* should be avoided as it's very hard to get the dependencies correct with recursive make. But anyways, this would work.

Comment: Hi, Felix Palmen. Thank you so much for answer. Your solution works. But I don't understand why use `?=`, I tried `=` and `:=` both don't work. I especially don't understand the difference between `?=` and `:=`. According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448910/what-is-the-difference-between-the-gnu-makefile-variable-assignments-a?rq=1  they are somewhat similiar

Comment: I suggest you [read the fine manual about that](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Setting.html#Setting) (because the distinction between `=` and `:=` is very important, but not relevant here). In short, `?=` only sets that value if it doesn't have a value yet, and `make` also takes variables from the environment. **But again:** If you have just one Makefile, **don't do that**. It's really a misuse of `make`.

Comment: Hi, @Felix Palmen. I found I still don't understand. I know `?=` only sets that value if it doesn't have a value yet. But I don't see any difference between using `?=` and `=` or `?=` in your last example, they all set var equal to 11, and there is no expansion issue. But the result is that only `?=` works for your last example

Comment: @user15964 you are **calling** `$(MAKE)` in a recipe, which starts a **second** instance of make. In this second instance, `var` is already said because the "parent" `make` exported it to the environment. Avoid recursive make...

Comment: Oh, so do you mean when call `$(MAKE)`, all things outside recipes in current makefile will be reevaluated, right?

Comment: @user15964 you are *calling `make`* -- what do you expect? This starts a new instance, so yes, of course.

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke make again from the recipe of `a`, you really launch a new make process that will parse again your makefile and thus, its first line, that assigns value 11 to variable `var`. Next, this second make invocation builds target `b` and echoes 11...

If you want to pass a variable value to a sub-make invocation you can do it on the command line with the `make VAR=VALUE ...` syntax. In your example, you could, for instance:

```
$ cat Makefile
var = 11

a:
    echo $(var)
    $(eval var=22)
    echo $(var)
    $(MAKE) var=$(var) b

b:
    echo $(var)

$ make a
echo 11
11
echo 22
22
make var=22 b
make[1]: Entering directory 'foo'
echo 22
22
make[1]: Leaving directory 'foo'
```

It works because variables that are assigned on the command line, by default, override the definitions found in the makefile (see the [make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Overriding)).

This command line assignment may look strange because it seems to assign the value of variable `var`  to itself but it does not. It assigns the current value of variable `var` of the **first (top) make invocation** to variable `var` of the **sub-make invocation**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. IMHO you should revert the order: ‘a’  depends on ‘b’
    var = 11
    b:var =22
    b: a
        echo b:$(var)
    a:
        echo: a:$(var)

Comment: Sorry for the code style, not simple from my mobile