# Makefile: macro is recast when including second file

Tags: makefile, multiple-makefiles

I have a make file that has two includes like this :

```
$ cat /src/Makefile
include ../rules.mk

Test:
    echo $(DIST_ROOT)

include src.base.mk

Test2: 
     echo $(DIST_ROOT)

. PHONY: Test Test2

$ cat /rules.mk
DIST_ROOT = $(abspath $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))

$ cat /src/src.base.mk
srcdir = $(DIST_ROOT)/src
```

The issue is that the output of both is `/src` but it should be `/`.

How does this happen and how can I fix this?

Comment: In `Test2` recipe do you really echo `$(DIST_ROOT)`? Isn't it `$(srcdir)`, instead? And when you write `/src`, isn't it `/src/src.base.mk`? And (it seems obvious but you did not specify this) do you invoke make from `/src`? And your` `Phony`, isn't it `.PHONY`?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet yes sorry. I tiped this on my smartphone. But the 2nd recipe is really "echo $(DIST_ROOT)".

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. `make Test` outputs `/src` and `make Test2` also outputs `/src`. And this is not surprising at all.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. But thats exactly the isue the output should be / not /src.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue and a fix.
To answer my own question:
When assigning a variable with just equal sign, the variable gets cast everytime its just.
What I needed to add was ":" so it gets casted once and is set as wanted.
Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448910/what-is-the-difference-between-the-gnu-makefile-variable-assignments-a).