# How do environment variables and macros interact in GNU Make?

Tags: environment-variables, gnu-make

In GNU Makefiles, there are often interactions between environment variables and parameters/variables/macros. There are also several different assignment operators, there are "override" variables that can be provided on the command line, and there is an `override` directive.

What are the precedence rules for these interactions?

Consider this Makefile:

```
# Use := to avoid infinite recursion of macro expansion
CFLAGS := -g -O2 $(CFLAGS)
hello: src/hello.c
    cc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

If you invoke `CFLAGS=-pipe make hello`, you get `cc -g -O2 -pipe -o hello src/hello.c`. If you invoke `make CFLAGS=-pipe hello`, you get `cc -pipe -o hello src/hello.c`. What's the difference?

And if you change the Makefile to:

```
CFLAGS ?= -g -O2 $(CFLAGS)
hello: src/hello.c
    cc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

You get `cc -pipe -o hello src/hello.c` in both cases.

Comment: Maybe a better title would be something like "When do Makefile variables get their values from the environment, command line or Makefile itself?". Also, another popular tag for `make` is `Makefile`.

Answer (score 2):

*This answer is based on information in the comments of https://stackoverflow.com/a/63187052/2954547, as well as the [GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html#Top).*

The precedence is, in order of strongest to weakest, is:

1. The `override` directive
2. Command-line override
3. `=`, `:=`
4. Environment variable
5. `?=`

There are several individual rules that interact to create this precedence:

- A macro is created for every environment variable. If e.g. `HOME` is set, there will be a `$(HOME)` macro.
- If a macro is already defined, `=` and `:=` overwrite the previous macro definition. This includes environment variables, which are (conceptually) created before the rest of the Makefile is interpreted. So `=` or `:=` will overwrite an environment variable. But if the environment variable is defined, it can still be referenced on the right-hand side of the assignment:

  ```
  CFLAGS := -g -O2 $(CFLAGS)
  ```

  Note that you had to use `:=` in this case, because if you used `=` you would get a macro that tried to expand itself recursively, forever, at run time.
- As per [section 6.5 of the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Setting.html#Setting), `VAR ?= val` is equivalent to:

  ```
  ifeq ($(origin VARIABLE), undefined)
    VAR = val
  endif
  ```

  Environment variables have their [origin](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Origin-Function.html#index-origin) set to `'environment'`, so `?=` will always be overridden by an environment variable. Unlike `=` and `:=`, if the environment variable is set, its corresponding assignment with `?=` will never even be invoked.
- Command-line "override variables" override all variables. This means that `make VAR=val` overrides the environment variable `VAR`, and the assignments `VAR = val`, `VAR := val`, and `VAR ?= val`.
- The `override` directive overrides everything, including command-line overrides.

Note that GNU Make has the `-e`/`--environment-overrides` option, which causes environment variables to override `=` and `:=`. This causes them to behave the same as command-line override variables with respect to macro definition , but (I think) the latter will still take precedence.

Comment: I would mention that "macro" and "variable" are used interchangeably here. 2. I would add a a documentation reference to `override` directive, and define or add a reference for "command-line override". Not everyone would know that "command-line override" means "variables set in `make` command line".

Comment: In "Command-line "override variables" override all variables", I believe, you mean "... override all assignments, except for `override`". Also, add a documentation reference to `override`.

Comment: Also `?=`, not `=?`.