# Why is Makefile export adding an extra `=` to my variables?

Tags: makefile, environment-variables

I have this Makefile:

```
export $(shell echo "truman=name")

env:
    export
```

When I run `make env`, I see:

```
export truman="name="
```

Why is there an extra `=` in my export?

Comment: Extremely funny. Can you try to `$(info <$(shell echo "truman=name")>)` and tell us its output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a Make bug, and I think I know what's going on.

`make` sees `export $(...)`, and thinks the entire `$(...)` is the variable name, without checking it for `=`. Since it thinks no value is specified, it adds `=` at the end.

Then the whole string `truman=name=` gets passed to something like [`putenv`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/putenv.3.html), which considers the *first* `=` to be the separator, and treats `name=` as the value.

As said in the other answers, the fix is to use `$(eval )`.

Comment: Yes, make is searching the word to find `=` _before_ it expands the value, not afterwards.  If there's no `=` before expansion, then make considers it to be a variable name with no assignment (e.g., `export foo`).  Whether that's a bug or not would need careful consideration as to the downsides of doing the expansion before parsing to find `=`.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly assign the value to the variable in the Makefile without using `echo`.

```
export truman=name

env:
    @echo $$truman
```

If you want to dynamically generate and export variables such as `truman=name`, `height=tall`, and `handsome=false`, you can use a loop in the shell command to assign each variable separately. Here's how you can do it:

```
export_vars := $(shell for var in "truman=name" "height=tall" "handsome=false"; do echo $$var; done)

$(foreach var,$(export_vars),$(eval export $(var)))

env:
    @echo truman=$$truman
    @echo height=$$height
    @echo handsome=$$handsome
```

Comment: I need to assign a number of dynamically generated vars, e.g. 

`export $(shell echo truman=name height=tall handsome=false)` all of which at present have an extra `=` appended to them.

Comment: I have edited my answer to handle dynamically generated vars like in your example

Answer (score 0):

The `$(shell ...)` invocation makes no sense at all here.

You simply want

```
export truman=name
```

(or possibly `truman := name` to avoid [lazy expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448910/what-is-the-difference-between-the-gnu-makefile-variable-assignments-a)).

If the value and the assignment comes from an external process, you can say

```
$(eval export $(shell echo gehzna=anzr | tr a-z n-za-m))
```